# two equal calculations not returning the same result

Tags: c++

I got two different .cpp files with two equal calculations.. But they don't return the same results?

## A code

```
double theta = (double)maxLoc.y/angleBins*CV_PI;
std::cout << theta << " " << abs(sin(theta)) << std::endl;
```

## A result

```
1.53589 0.999391
```

## B code

```
double theta = (double)maxLoc.y / angleBins * CV_PI;
std::cout << theta << " " << abs(sin(theta)) << std::endl;
```

## B result

```
1.53589 0
```

Comment: This is impossible. Spacing literally makes no difference (literally!). You must be doing something else different. As always, and you should know this by now, you must **post a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: `std::abs` solved it....

Comment: Regardless, the question is broken, and must be fixed or it'll be closed. Every question on this site must hold general value not just to the author but to future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably calling the `abs` function from C in the second code snippet which takes an `int` as parameter. Using `std::abs` in both code snippets (and the correct header `#include<cmath>`) will fix the problem.

Comment: "Code" in this context is an uncountable noun; as such, "codes" is incorrect here.

Comment: @PreferenceBean: I replaced it by `code snippets`. I hope it sounds better :-)